# Change color of a Video.js marker

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I have an issue with my project. I used the very useful "Creating a video player with time markers — step by step" project, available here: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/03/17/creating-video-player-with-time-markers

I created my own code like this:

```js
    function EnvoiQ(){
       var current = video.currentTime();
       var texteQ = $("#texteQ").val();

       video.markers.add({
              markers: {time: current,  text: texteQ},
            });
      }
```

```html
<button id="question" onclick="EnvoiQ()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
```

When I click my "Hey" button, I create a new marker exactly where I clicked the button.

But now, I would like to edit the color of my marker. Indeed, I got 2 buttons, when I click on the first one, my marker should be red, and when I click on the second, my marker sould be yellow.

The problem is: after many hours of manipulations, I can't make one color correspond to one button. The marker is a JS object and its color is defined like that:

```js
var e = {
        markerStyle: {
            width: "7px",
            "border-radius": "30%",
            "background-color": "red"
        },
```

By default the color is red, but how could I change this color according to the button I click?

Comment: Note that the project blog post you mention has moved here: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2016/03/creating-video-player-with-time-markers/

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be addressed in an [issue](https://github.com/spchuang/videojs-markers/issues/46) on the project's GitHub page. I've replicated the project owner's answer below for posterity:

> Do you only want to change 1 particular marker or all? What you can do
>   is assigned a custom marker class, as provided in the `markers` array.
>   Then in the callback of `onMarkerReached` or `onMarkerClick`, manually
>   change the css of such class.
>
> Let me know if that works.
>
> ```
> // setup plugin
> player.markers({
>    onMarkerClick: function(marker) {
>      // change stlye here based on marker.class
>    },
>    markers: [{
>       time: 9.5, 
>       text: "marker", 
>       overlayText: 'overlay', 
>       class: 'custom-marker1'
>    }]
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. Let me know if this helps!

```
<button id="question" onclick="e.markerStyle['background-color']='red'; EnvoiQ();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
<button id="question" onclick="e.markerStyle['background-color']='yellow'; EnvoiQ();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the idea, indeed I want to change the markerStyle property according to my buttons. But your code proposal doesn't work.